# Module resolution with yarn / npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, es6-modules, yarn-v2

I am playing around with remix and mui v5.
Using npm I get the following error when running `npm run dev`

```
Error: Directory import '.../playground/remix-mui-dev/node_modules/@mui/material/styles' is not supported resolving ES modules imported from .../playground/remix-mui-dev/build/index.js
```

I expected that this should work.

I have seen a lot of hints on the net what might be the problem.
But then I tried yarn (4.1.1) with pnp resolution: No error

So I switched to yarn with node-modules: Same error as with npm.

I am not at all an expert in TS / frontend development and tooling.
I would like to better understand what the interplay between the TS / JS module resolution and the package managers is.
But lacking the knowledge, I do not really find the references on the net, that point me in the right direction.

I have created a [repo](https://github.com/rattermeyer/remix-mui-dev) with two branches (main=> npm and yarn for yarn)

Answer (score 1):

it's because in some file `theme.ts` and `theme-options.ts` you import dependencies from `@mui/material/styles` and not from `@mui/material`

the `index.js` that export the needed function in the node module is in the root folder of @mui/material change the import like below sample to make run your application

```
import { ThemeOptions } from '@mui/material';
```

Comment: Ok. checked that. Changing import of ThemeOptions was not necessary, but createTheme.
However, does this mean, I should open an issue on MUI documentation?
The [documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/) explicitely shows the form `import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
`
Still I am confused that it is working in yarn.

Comment: yes in that case it's the documentation that is not updated as the true way to use it. If you want to change that you can contact MUI team or make an issue in github https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/master/docs